# Почему не работает запрос на авторизацию

Tags: java, spring-security

Есть рабочая авторизация на прошлой версии security, пытался сделать на новой но не работает запрос на аутентификацию.
Вот контроллер

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
  @Autowired
  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @Autowired
  PasswordEncoder encoder;

  @Autowired
  JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @GetMapping("/token/check")
  public String validateToken(){
    return "true";
  }

  @PostMapping("/signin")
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    System.out.println(loginRequest.getUsername() + " " + loginRequest.getPassword());

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();    
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                         userDetails.getId(),
                         userDetails.getUsername(), 
                         userDetails.getEmail(), 
                         roles));
  }

  @PostMapping("/signup")
  public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
      return ResponseEntity
          .badRequest()
          .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
    }

    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
      return ResponseEntity
          .badRequest()
          .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
    }

    // Create new user's account
    User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), 
               signUpRequest.getEmail(),
               encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

    Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    if (strRoles == null) {
      Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
      roles.add(userRole);
    } else {
      strRoles.forEach(role -> {
        switch (role) {
        case "admin":
          Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
          roles.add(adminRole);

          break;
        case "mod":
          Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
          roles.add(modRole);

          break;
        default:
          Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
          roles.add(userRole);
        }
      });
    }

    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
  }
}
```

Конфиг security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
       
      authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   
      return authProvider;
  }
  
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Конечная jwt

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
      throws IOException {
    logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
    body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
    body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
  }

}
```

И фильтр

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Autowired
  private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      String jwt = parseJwt(request);
      if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails,
                null,
                userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Запрос на регистрацию работает, а вот уже на аутентификацию выдает ошибку в конечной jwt
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что означает прошлой версии и настоящей? у вас спрнг бут или просто спрнг? какая актуальная версия и какая прошлая?

Comment: spring boot, на 2.7.3 работало, 3.0.0 не получается сделать

Comment: там много отличий))а версия джавы у вас какая сейчас?

Comment: текущая 17, ну вдруг кто поможет)